# Recursion in C unable to return result from the prototype!?

Tags: recursion

I'm not sure why this recursion is not working! I'm trying to get the total of an input from i=0 to n. I'm also testing recursion instead of 'for loop' to see how it performs. Program runs properly but stops after the input. I would appreciate any comments, thx!

```
int sigma (int n)
{
    if (n <= 0) // Base Call
        return 1;
    else {
        printf ("%d", n);
        int sum = sigma( n+sigma(n-1) ); 
        return sum;
    }

    // recursive call to calculate any sum>0; 
    // for example: input=3; sum=(3+sigma(3-1)); sum=(3+sigma(2))
    // do sigma(2)=2+sigma(2-1)=2+sigma(1);
    // so sigma(1)=1+sigma(1-1)=1+sigma(0)=1; 
    // finally, sigma(3)=3+2+1+0=6
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])   
{ 
    int n;

    printf("Enter a positive integer for sum : ");
    scanf( " %d ", &n);

    int sum = sigma(n);
    printf("The sum of all numbers for your entry: %d\n", sum);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I could not understand what what you meant by :"Program runs properly but stops after the input."

Comment: It just keeps adding to the argument to sigma until I suppose eventually it runs out of memory.

Comment: That is because you are recursively calling sigma(sigma) in your code. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Change 
    `int sum = sigma( n+sigma(n-1) );` 
to
     `int sum = n + sigma( n-1 );`

As you've written it, calling `sigma(3)` then calls `sigma(5)`, etc...

Also, return 0 from the guard case, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
int sum = n + sigma(n-1)
```

Comment: And have the `if` branch return 0 rather than 1.

Comment: Omg! can't believe myself didn't see that one:)

Thanks to you all for quick reply!